# vertical align of top navigation menu items

Tags: html, css

This is what like my menu is now:

[image]

As you can see I wish to have multi-line menu items.
What I wonder now is how to vertically align all my menu items?

Here is the current HTML structure:

```
<nav><div>
<ul>
<li><a>menu-item</a></li>
....
</ul>
</div></nav>
```

Any suggestion welcome. Thanks!

Comment: The multiline ones make this difficult.

Comment: Yes, I know it does. I have been sitting for hours on this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
nav {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

    nav ul {
        display: table-row;
    }

        nav ul li {
            display: table-cell;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
```

Comment: They don't work in IE7 and below though. If that matters. But you can give this styling only to modern browsers (and keep your old styling for IE<8) by changing the selectors to start with `body > nav` (or whatever works).